# How I can add two key in the one filter? [emacs | org-mode | org-agenda-custom-commands]

Tags: emacs, org-mode

We have example:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands 
  '(("c" "Desk Work" tags-todo "computer" ;; (1) (2) (3) (4)
     ((org-agenda-files '("~/org/widgets.org" "~/org/clients.org")) ;; (5)
      (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-up effort-down))) ;; (5) cont.
     ("~/computer.html")) ;; (6)
    ;; ...other commands here
    ))
```

If user send **C-a c** this example is start

Questions:
I need to get this code could work with a few characters. For example, that I may gain **C-a c** or **C-a 3**, and at the same time carried out the same code.
**C-a c = C-a 3**

I need see in the agenda buffer:

```
"c" or "3" "Desk Work"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to define two keys with the same agenda command.  I would put the relevant parts of the agenda command in a variable, like so:

```el
(defvar my/org-agenda-desk-work
  '(tags-todo "computer"
    ((org-agenda-files '("~/org/widgets.org" "~/org/clients.org"))
     (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-up effort-down)))
    ("~/computer.html"))
  "Custom agenda command for desk work.
The value (a list form) is the correct format to be the tail of
an entry in `org-agenda-custom-commands', lacking only the key
used to trigger the agenda and a name.")
```

If the command will differ a little between the keys, you could instead use a function to parametrize as necessary:

```el
(defun my/org-agenda-desk-work-tagged (tag)
  "Return desk work agenda command for TAG.

The return value (a list form) is the correct format to be the
tail of an entry in `org-agenda-custom-commands', lacking only
the key used to trigger the agenda and a name"
  `("Desk Work" tags-todo ,tag
    ((org-agenda-files '("~/org/widgets.org" "~/org/clients.org"))
     (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-up effort-down)))
    ("~/computer.html")))
```

To use these, you would do something like this:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands 
      `(("c" "Desk Work" ,@my/org-agenda-desk-work)
        ("3" "Desk Work" ,@my/org-agenda-desk-work)
        ("f" "Desk Work Foo" ,@(my/org-agenda-desk-work-tagged "foo"))
        ;; ...other commands here
        ))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think another